# Amazon SP API Authentication with MWS keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am new to programming and was given a project to integrate Amazon API for a client who has a FBA Seller Account on Amazon. 
I was given the following information from their account: 
Seller ID, Marketplace ID, Access Key, and Secret Key. 
The client has only used this with MWS API.
 My question is if these keys will work for the SP API and what additional info do I need from the client in order to set up authentication. I tried reading [this guide](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md) but I am still not clear if the keys I have can be used to replace some of these steps, and if so which ones.

Answer (score 0):

No the MWS credentials will not work. You need a whole new set of credentials by following the guide you linked. That is what everyone else has to do.